# lucene group by

Tags: lucene, group-by

hi have index simple document where you have 2 fields:

```
1. profileId as long

2. profileAttribute as long.
```

i need to know how many profileId's have a certain set of attribute.

for example i index:

```
doc1: profileId:1 , profileAttribute = 55
doc2: profileId:1 , profileAttribute = 57
doc3: profileId:2 , profileAttribute = 55
```

and i want to know how many profiles have both attribute 55 and 57 
in this example the answer is 1 cuz only profile id 1 have both attributes

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2):

You can search for `profileAttribute:(57 OR 55)` and then iterate over the results and put their `profileId` property in a set in order to count the total number of unique `profileId`s.

But you need to know that Lucene will perform poorly at this compared to, say, a RDBMS. This is because Lucene is an inverted index, meaning it is very good at retrieving the top documents that match a query. It is however not very good at iterating over the stored fields of a large number of documents.

However, if `profileId` is single-valued and indexed, you can get its values using Lucene's fieldCache which will prevent you from performing costly disk accesses. The drawback is that this fieldCache will use a lot of memory (depending on the size of your index) and take time to load every time you (re-)open your index.

If changing the index format is acceptable, this solution can be improved by making `profileId`s uniques, your index would have the following format :

```
doc1: profileId: [1], profileAttribute: [55, 57]
doc2: profileId: [2], profileAttribute: [55]
```

The difference is that `profileId`s are unique and `profileAttribute` is now a multi-valued field. To count the number of `profileId`s for a given set of `profileAttribute`, you now only need to query for the list of `profileAttribute` (as previously) and use a [TotalHitCountCollector](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_1_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/TotalHitCountCollector.html).

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer.
the first 2 lines of your answer will probably solve my issue.
also i will look at your fieldCache proposal (since i am new to lucene and not sure how this fieldCache work) so thanks for pointing that out for me.